# Procedure select 1 and delete

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I am trying to create a procedure that
  1. Selects the first record.
  2. Deletes the record and returns it to the caller.

I have the following code (mind you I am fairly new to PLSQL).
I got it from looking at other SO questions and the oracle docs.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE TAKE_1_DELETE_1
AS
BEGIN
DELETE FROM my_table
where rownum = 1
  RETURNING *
  INTO v_event;
END TAKE_1_DELETE_1;
```

I get the following error:

```
[Error] PLS-00103 (7: 3): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following:

   ; <an identifier> <a double-quoted delimited-identifier>
   current delete exists prior <a single-quoted SQL st
```

I have tried numerous things, but none have worked thus far.

Our Data-Warehouse people are saying "We don't know what is wrong".

Dear SO gods... what do I need to do, to get my procedure to do what I want? :)

Comment: You haven't declared the v_event variable, fwiw. (That isn't the cause of your error above, but once that's corrected, you'll get another error because of the variable!)

Comment: @Boneist thanks for the heads-up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a couple of errors here:

1. You haven't declared `v_event` so you're trying to return data into a uninstantiated variable/out parameter
2. [You can't "return" `*`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/returninginto_clause.htm#LNPLS01354) you have to explicitly state all columns - this is the actual error you're getting

Assuming a table that looks like this

```
create table my_table (a number, b number);
```

Your procedure would look like the following:

```
create or replace procedure take_1_delete_1 is
   v_event my_table%rowtype;
begin

   delete from my_table
    where rownum = 1
   returning a, b
     into v_event;

end take_1_delete_1;
```

Or, if you wanted to use the returning value outside the procedure you can use an OUT parameter rather than declaring a local variable

```
create or replace procedure take_1_delete_1 (p_event out my_table%rowtype) is
begin

   delete from my_table
    where rownum = 1
   returning a, b
     into p_event;

end take_1_delete_1;
```

Comment: Ben of Stack Overflow, you are a god among men.